# C++ - Background subtraction in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a project on background subtraction using OpenCV, but my output highlight result was not clear.

This is my coding:

```
#include < stdio.h>
#include < iostream>

#include < opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include < opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include < opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include < opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>


#ifdef _DEBUG        
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_core2410d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_imgproc2410d.lib")   //MAT processing
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_objdetect2410d.lib") //HOGDescriptor
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_gpu2410d.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_features2d2410d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_highgui2410d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_ml2410d.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_stitching2410d.lib");
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_nonfree2410d.lib");
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_video2410d.lib")
#else
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_core2410.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_imgproc2410.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_objdetect2410.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_gpu2410.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_features2d2410.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_highgui2410.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_ml2410.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_stitching2410.lib");
//#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_nonfree2410.lib");
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_video2410d.lib")
#endif 

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;

int main()
{

 //global variables
 Mat frame; //current frame
 Mat resizeF;
 Mat fgMaskMOG; //fg mask generated by MOG method
 Mat blob;
 Mat back;

 Ptr< BackgroundSubtractor> pMOG; //MOG Background subtractor




 pMOG = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG();



 char fileName[100] = "C:\\Users\\SamBCChan\\Desktop\\FYP Video\\demo4.mp4"; //Gate1_175_p1.avi"; //mm2.avi"; //";//_p1.avi";
 VideoCapture stream1(fileName);   //0 is the id of video device.0 if you have only one camera   

 Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(3, 3), Point(1,1) );   

 //unconditional loop   
 while (true) {   
  Mat cameraFrame;   
  if(!(stream1.read(frame))) //get one frame form video   
   break;

  resize(frame, resizeF, Size(frame.size().width/2, frame.size().height/2) );
  pMOG->operator()(resizeF, fgMaskMOG);

  //morphologyEx(fgMaskGMG, fgMaskGMG, CV_MOP_OPEN, element); 
  pMOG->getBackgroundImage(back); 
  cv::erode(fgMaskMOG,fgMaskMOG,cv::Mat());
  cv::dilate(fgMaskMOG,fgMaskMOG,cv::Mat());
  cv::findContours(fgMaskMOG,contours,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
        cv::cvtColor(fgMaskMOG,blob,CV_GRAY2RGB);
        cv::drawContours(blob,contours,-1,cv::Scalar(255,255,255),CV_FILLED,8);
         int cmin= 500; //min connected contours
        int cmax= 10000; //max connected contours
        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> >::iterator itc=contours.begin();
        while (itc!=contours.end()) {
            if (itc->size() > cmin || itc->size() < cmax){
                std::vector<cv::Point> pts = *itc;
                cv::Mat pointsMatrix = cv::Mat(pts);
                cv::Scalar color( 0, 255, 0 );
                cv::Rect r0= cv::boundingRect(pointsMatrix);
                cv::rectangle(resizeF,r0,color,2);
                ++itc;
            }else{++itc;}
        }


  imshow("Origin", resizeF);
  imshow("MOG", fgMaskMOG);
  imshow("Blob",blob);


  if (waitKey(30) >= 0)   
   break;   
 }
 return 0;
}
```

My result came out as shown here. I need to make it draw a rectangle around the moving object properly, but it came out like this.

http://dc589.2shared.com/download/hnstQJ35/post_pic2.PNG?tsid=20150504-033417-c4d04967

Could someone tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the constructor of [BackgroundSubtractorMOG](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/video/BackgroundSubtractorMOG.html).
There is a bunch of parameter that you might want to play with. There is no best values, it depends on your video.

- history – Length of the history.
- nmixtures – Number of Gaussian mixtures.
- backgroundRatio – Background ratio.
- noiseSigma – Noise strength.

For more details take a look at the original paper describing the method:
http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/R.Bowden/publications/avbs01/avbs01.pdf

Note that opencv implements other background subtraction methods, in particular [BackgroundSubtractorMOG2](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/video/BackgroundSubtractorMOG2.html), for which the number of gaussians is deduced automatically from the data.